# Flask - WTF - Input Required Validator - Restrict the request from being posted (Stay on page)

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I am learning about using WTForms and Flask together on a new application proof of concept.

I Have A Form. The Goal is to require at least 3 characters of a Last Name.

```
class PersonByNameForm(Form):
    first_name = StringField('First Name', filters=none_filter)
    last_name = StringField(validators=[InputRequired('Enter a Last Name'), Length(min=3)])
    submit = SubmitField('SUBMIT')
```

I render the form as such

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = PersonByNameForm()
        return render_template('front_page.html', form=form)
```

html

```
 <form action="person_profiles" method="post">
                {{form.hidden_tag()}}
                {{form.first_name.label}}
                {{form.first_name}}
                {{form.last_name.label}}
                {{form.last_name}}
                {{form.submit}}
            </form>
```

The Form itself Posts the data to

```
@app.route('/person_profiles', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def person_profiles():

    if request.method == 'GET':
        # This is just place holder but this view will have copy of the form
        form = PersonByNameForm()
        form2 = FindPersonForm()
        return render_template('person_profile.html', context=[], form=form, form2=form2)

    else:

        form = PersonProfileForm(request.form)

        if form.validate_on_submit():
            query = Session.query(schema.Person)
            first_name = form.first_name.data
            last_name = form.last_name.data
            print(first_name, last_name)
            if first_name:
                query = query.filter(schema.Person.first_name.contains(first_name))
            if last_name:
                query = query.filter(schema.Person.last_name.contains(last_name))

            return render_template('person_profile.html', context=query.all())
        else:
            print(form.errors)
            error = form.errors
            flash_errors(form, 'test')
            return render_template('person_profile.html', error=error, form=form)
```

The Form will `validate_on_submit()` properly, and head into the else block print the form.error of `{'last_name': ['Enter a Last Name']}`

The Issue I have is, I do not want to actually render the template (It's just there cuz I have to return a response for now). And no error is flashed on screen.

How do I restrict the navigation until x characters are in the box? and flash the message if it does not validate?

Thanks for reading

Comment: Can the downvoters please comment as to why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit unclear to me what your issue is.

> The Form will validate_on_submit() properly

So entered string is at least 3 chars long, right?

> The Issue I have is, I do not want to actually render the template (It's just there cuz I have to return a response for now). And no error is flashed on screen.

To flash the error message, after you call to `flash`, render the template again with the values already entered. You have to render something to include the flash messages.

> How do I restrict the navigation until x characters are in the box? and flash the message if it does not validate?

Do you want to prevent the form from being submitted (client-side) until there are at least 3 characters in name?

This is achievable by passing `max_length=3` when calling the field in the template :

```
{{form.last_name(max_length=3)}}
```

Obviously the issue here is that you're passing 3 directly in the template. AFAIK, WTForms does not do that automatically for you.

Comment: Hi Jerome, thanks for your input. By `properly` I mean that `validate_on_submit is false when submitted with no data. (as expected). However, I cannot seem to get anything to flash on the screen

Comment: After flash_errors, you need to render a template. In fact I'm surprised you don't get an error like "the function does not return anything" when you get in the `else` case.

Comment: I do, I just updated the code to the current status. It doesn't flash, but I can send in an `error` variable